# how to prevent multiple function call in react js on value change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I want to prevent a multiple function call on user action .In my demo application I have a **TABS** and **input field**. I want to call a function on user **TAB change**  and **when user type anything on input field** to call same function. Also reset the input field value when user change the tab .

Problem is my function is called **twice** when I change the tab. why ? I think it is due to setState only.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-leaf-pi3ykn?file=/src/App.tsx

```
 const AsyncCall = () => {
    console.log("AsyncCallAsyncCallAsyncCallAsyncCall");
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("init");
    AsyncCall();
  }, [value, textValue]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("reset value");
    setTextValue("");
  }, [value]);
```

Step to reproduce

1. Run Application **AsyncCall**  function call only one time
2. Type some text on input field example "abc". Every time it call function **which is correct behaviour**
3. clear console logs
4. Switch the second tab. if you see **AsyncCall** function call twice . I need to call only one time . NOT two times .this is the bug . I need to reset the input field also when user switch tabs

any way to prevent . I tried to use **ref** nothing works for me

**I want to call function every textfield value change and tab change . But when user change Tab I need to reset the textfield value also**
any suggestion ?

Comment: a small question, are you willing to call the async function on every single change?

Comment: It's due to the second useEffect.

Comment: remove second useEffect and add "setTextValue("")" inside "handleChange" function and it will resolve you issue.

Comment: Why dont call AsyncCall() directly from onChange of <TextField /> and <Tabs/> instead.

Get rid of both useEffect()

Comment: e you willing to call the async function on every single change ??

Comment: yes I want to call function every change

Comment: I want to call function every textfield value change and tab change . But when user change Tab I need to reset the textfield value also

Comment: @ShreyaKarunakar better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can call your async call in TextField onChange like this

```js
onChange={(e) => {
            setTextValue(e.target.value);
            AsyncCall();
}}
```

and can reset your value in Tabs onChange

```js
handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    setTextValue("");
  }
```

Get rid of both useEffect they are unnecessary here

Answer (score 0):

According to your need

> I want to call function every textfield value change and tab change .
> But when user change Tab I need to reset the textfield value also

Let see the issue in your code.

```
    React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("init");
    AsyncCall();
  }, [value, textValue]);
```

When every value and textValue changes your useEffect gonna invoke. We can remove this useEffect if we call `AsyncCall()` method inside your valueChange method.

For text field

```
const handleTextChange = () => {

setTextValue(e.target.value);
    AsyncCall();
}
     <TextField
              id="outlined-basic"
              onChange={handleTextChange} // i name it handleTextChange
              value={textValue}
              label="Outlined"
              variant="outlined"/>
```

Now whenever you textValue gonna change it will call `AsyncCall()` method.

For tabs

```
 const handleChange = ()=>{
     setValue(newValue);
// resetting text value as you want to reset it on tab change 
        setTextValue(""); 
// Calling AsyncCall() on Tab menu change
        AsyncCall();
    }
          <Tabs
              value={value}
              onChange={handleChange}
              aria-label="basic tabs example"
            >
    </Tabs>
```

Now, there is no need for these useEffects

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("init");
    AsyncCall();
  }, [value, textValue]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("reset value");
    setTextValue("");
  }, [value]);
```

**Suggestion**: For textValue you can use De-bounce technique to avid unnecessary re-rendering
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/debouncing-explained/

Answer (score -1):

Paste this code in your `handleChange` method

```
 setValue(newValue);
 setTextValue("")
```

and remove you second `useEffect()` hook

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("reset value");
    setTextValue("");
  }, [value]);
```